# VLC is keeping computer active , and preventing it from going to sleep or display screensaver ?

Tags: windows-7, windows, vlc-media-player, power-management, screensaver

title pretty much says it all

whenever I'm running vlc (minimized and not active)  computer can't go to sleep nor display screensaver ?

running `powercfg -requests` displays vlc along with realtek high definition ..

wondering if there is away to prevent / exclude vlc from requesting power ..

Comment: Funny, I have the opposite problem: A started to play a file, but after a few minutes Windows goes to sleep, stopping the playback. :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Open VLC
- Select Tools/Preferences
- At the bottom left is "Show settings" - select `All`
- Select Video
- on the right, uncheck "Disable Screensaver"
- Click Save

Comment: Without having tested it, this just seems to go to the other extreme, allowing a screensaver and perhaps even standby to interrupt while playing video, creating a new and opposite problem. The sensible, intelligent behavior would be that VLC would allow screensavers and standby when it is open but not playing anything, block screensavers and standby when it is playing video, and block standby but perhaps not screensavers when it is playing audio. Can VLC do that, and if so, how?

Comment: @Jesper after testing it, VLC actually does exactly that: if you "Disable Screensaver" it only prevents sleep when playing while during pause it will allowing computer to sleep